# .htaccess RewriteRule for multiple subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We are moving to another domain and want to redirect all old traffic:

```
en.site1.com/whatever >>> en.site2.com/whatever
cz.site1.com/whatever >>> cz.site2.com/whatever
fr.site1.com/whatever >>> fr.site2.com/whatever
# ...and so on
```

We are currently using .htaccess for redirects, so we would prefer a solution using that. RewriteRule itself doesn't see the domain name (*.example.com), so we have to use RewriteConds:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} en.site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://en.site2.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cz.site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cz.site2.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} fr.site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.site2.com/$1 [R=301]

# ...and so on
```

Doing this for each of X supported languages is overly verbose. I imagine a solution that would use a regex or something, instead of listing all languages:

```
# $0 is the regex match from RewriteCond
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$0.site2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Is that possible? Or is there any other way in .htaccess that doesn't include extensive copypasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* capture regex variables from `RewriteCond` in much the same way as you can from `RewriteRule`.

The difference in syntax, when you back-reference the captured variables, is that you use `%` instead of `$`.

**Eg.** Instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} en.site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://en.site2.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} cz.site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cz.site2.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} fr.site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.site2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z]{2}).site1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.site2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like charm. When I knew what to look for, I even found a mention about this in documentation.
For reference and later readers:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
(Section about RewriteCond Directive)

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple sub domains to redirect particular specific path redirection. 
   Please add below code in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ abcd.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ab.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ abs.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```